# How can I safely uninstall Perkus Maximus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I installed Perkus Maximus before I ever created any save games. Now that I've played with it for awhile, I'm considering uninstalling it. I know I'll have to start over with all of my characters, and I'm fine with that.

What I'm not sure about is how to uninstall Perkus. Do I just disable it in NMM? Or are there additional steps I need to do to make sure everything runs properly? I've done a few searches, and found plenty of info on installing Perma, but none on uninstalling it.

Could I perhaps get some pointers in the correct direction?

As a side question, will I be able to just re-activate Perkus and resume with my old saves if I decide I like it again?

Comment: My first thought would be to go onto the NMM or Steam Workshop page for the mod and look for uninstall instructions from the author. If none are visible, ask in the comments section there.

Comment: Life is easier if you use Mod Organizer instead of NMM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any save games made while using PerMa will not work (well) after uninstalling it; it modifies too much of the game. Uninstalling the mod to start a new game should be simple enough to do. You should also remove any other compatibility patches you might have for it and other mods that depend on it.

### Installed via NMM (or another mod manager)

Simply deactivate/uninstall the mod from the manager (the same way you installed it, but in reverse).

If you have mods that work differently with and without PerMa installed, you should check their documentation for what to do with them. The safest bet is probably to reinstall them.

### Installed manually

Deactivate the ESP's via Skyrim Launcher and remove all the files you extracted when installing the mod.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you just have to remove the patch, and deactivate the mod. You *will* have to start over your game, *but*... there is another way.

A mod called Main Menu puts skyui in the main menu, *and* adds save game sorting by characters.

I would like to recommend Requiem however. It is soooo much better IMO, and will be realistic but difficult, and have lots of patches, and an auto patcher.

Comment: For a person unfamiliar with how mod files work, please define removing the patch.

Comment: @TommyMyron removing mod related files after deactivating it.